# Emacs shows up a buffer even if I told it to not do so

Tags: buffers, shell

I'm writing a couple of functions to help me in Java development (may turn into a package someday).
To extract the classpath for my project, I use Maven (`mvn dependency:build-classpath`), then I filter its output. To do so, I have the following snippet in my function:

```lisp
(let ((classpath-buffer (get-buffer-create "*mvn-classpath*")))
  (shell-command
   (format "mvn -f %s dependency:build-classpath -Dmdep.includeScope=runtime"
           project-root)
   classpath-buffer
   classpath-buffer)
  (let ((basic-classpath
         (with-current-buffer "*mvn-classpath*"
           (goto-char (point-min))
           (delete-matching-lines "\\[INFO\\]\\|\\[WARNING\\]")
           ;; ignore ending newline
           (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (- (point-max) 1)))))
    (concat project-root "target/classes:" basic-classpath)))
```

As you can see I

1. Create a buffer named `*mvn-classpath*`
2. launch a shell command and redirect the output to it
3. use the macro `with-current-buffer` to operate on the text (and delete lines using a regex)
4. finally, construct the classpath

To make the buffer `*mvn-classpath*` not show up every time, I also added in the file

```lisp
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
             '("*mvn-classpath*" display-buffer-no-window (nil)))
```

However, when I launch the function, this buffer **does show up** in split-screen. **How can I make it stay "silent"?**

Note that, for a similar purpose, I also use a buffer named `*java-grep*`:

```lisp
(let ((project-root (projectile-acquire-root))
      (output-buffer (get-buffer-create "*java-grep*")))
  (shell-command
   (format "grep --include=\\*.java -rnwl \'%s\' -e \'%s\'"
           project-root
           "public[[:space:]]\\+static[[:space:]]\\+void[[:space:]]\\+main")
   output-buffer
   output-buffer)
  ...)
;; rest of the code
```

In that case, the buffer **doesn't show up**, even without adding `(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist '("*java-grep*" display-buffer-no-window (nil)))`. What is the difference between the two?

Edit: my Emacs version is `GNU Emacs 28.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.33, cairo version 1.17.6) of 2022-04-28`

Comment: Next time, please indent your code properly. (Use `M-x untabify` first.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shell-command` always `DISPLAY`s.

You can use `call-process-shell-command` with `DISPLAY` set to nil.

[`shell-command`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/86d128c6c3acca1665addc65aa43ff80572f46e8/lisp/simple.el#L4413) in turn calls [`call-process-shell-command`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/86d128c6c3acca1665addc65aa43ff80572f46e8/lisp/simple.el#L4524) with `DISPLAY` set to `t`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `with-temp-buffer` or `with-output-to-string` instead. These create temporary unnamed buffers that are never shown to the user, and then destroy them once they’re done.

Comment: Thanks, it should work, but I'd like to keep a copy of it. Since I need to parse and extract some text from it, I use `delete-matching-lines` and I keep the rest, as you see in my first snippet. I don't know if this is the best way to do so: do you have any suggestion? For instance, in case the command returned some error, the returned classpath gets polluted with errors, and having a copy of the output aids in understanding what went wrong. Tbh, calling `compile` before should solve the problem, though. I'll try to trigger classpath generation only if compilation went successful.

Comment: Both of my suggestions would simply replace `(with-current-buffer "*mvn-classpath*"`. If you replaced that with `with-temp-buffer`, the rest of the code would work exactly the same. If you replaced it with `with-output-to-string`, it would automatically return a string containing whatever the buffer held, meaning you could get rid of you call to `buffer-substring-no-properties` as well. Of course you would still want to remove the newline, but that can be done by any of several means.

Comment: Thanks, that gives me new things to consider! Right now I think I'll keep the buffer, because Maven is a bit slow in producing outputs and I think I'm going to use the `*mvn-classpath*` buffer as a cache, checking if the `pom.xml` has been modified in the meanwhile. As a side note, I sometimes struggled to remove the trailing newline(s) from a file: how would you do that? `end-of-buffer`, `search-backward`, and `delete-region`?

Comment: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ElispCookbook#h5o-6

Comment: Lots of ways to do it.